# How to temporary disable Timer when modal window is shown?

Tags: vb.net

I have a window with timer (System.Windows.Forms.Timer) that ticks every minute and refreshes DataGridView. I want to temporary disable ticks whenever any modal window is displayed (like message dialog). Of course I can do it this way:

```
Timer1.Enabled=False
'show modal dialog here
Timer1.Enabled=True
```

Any idea to make it in a more "nice" way? So that timer was automatically suspended when any dialog box is shown?

Generally I believe this would be enough:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (modal any modal dialog active) Then Exit Sub
    ....
End Sub
```

Note: When there is no active dialog, the timer must tick even when main window is minimized or when another application has focus.

Comment: No, there is no nice way.  Always avoid [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: see: [Application.EnterThreadModal Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enterthreadmodal?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the related [Application.LeaveThreadModal Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.leavethreadmodal?view=netframework-4.7.2).  Pay attention to the **Remarks** section.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Works perfect! And very nice. :-)